# Must a class name be fully qualified when we already set -classpath to locate that file?

Tags: java

Example:

I have a class called ProgA

```
package test;
public class ProgA
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   { 
      ProgB pb = new ProgB();
      pb.callMe();
   }
}
```

Now I have the ProgB like below:

```
package test2;
public class ProgB
{
   public void callMe()
   {
     System.out.println("inside callme");
   }
}
```

After compiling ProgB.java its class file is generated in the test2 package. Now when I try to compile ProgA.java using this command:

```
javac -cp C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\test2 ProgA.java
```

I get the error that it cannot find ProgB. 
My question is why cant java look inside the class path to find ProgB.class file and compile my ProgA.java successfully? The code works fine when I specify the fully qualified class name of ProgB inside ProgA.java code and run with the classpath set to `-classpath C:\Users\MyName\Desktop`. Why to have the fully quilified name when I am already specifying the full class path to find ProgB.  I am not clear with that concept of classpath and fully qualified class name. Please explain me. Thank you

Comment: I believe you need to import it first. Something like `import test2.ProgB;`. I'm not sure since it was decades ago when I took a dip into Java.

Comment: The two classes are in different packages. (test and test2) They won't look outside their own package unless specified.

Comment: So @KRichardson what you are trying to say is we need to tell compiler that ProgB is not in the same package as ProgA by specifying its fully qualified name. Without which compiler thinks that ProgB is in the same package as ProgA and doesnt even look at classpath for scanning?

Comment: Right, the class won't look outside its own package unless you tell it to. This prevents problems ambiguity, where with multiple packages may have classes with the same name.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a class from another package, you need to either use the fully qualified class name, or have an `import` statement. This is a `.java` source code requirement. It can't be fixed simply by fiddling with the compiler's classpath.

Without an import statement, unqualified names are assumed to belong to the current source file's package. If you're in a `package test` file, the identifier `ProgB` will match `test.ProgB` but not `test2.ProgB`. The compiler won't search other packages unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

First you would need to import the class.  This is why it asks you to use a fully qualified class name.  You cannot use a class that is not in the same package without importing it (or using the fully qualified class name).

```
import test2.ProgB;
```

Then while compiling, you should provide the class path till the root location, the compiler will look for the class using the package name as the path.

Your compile command should be.

```
javac -cp C:\Users\MyName\Desktop ProgA.java
```